# How can I return elements from a list with the number of occurrence in a document?

Tags: python, count

I am currently blocked with this Python exercise. I want to know the occurrence of a word and its synonyms in a corpus of documents.

An Entry is a class with the attributes "word" and "synonyms".

```
class Entry :
def __init__(self, input_word, input_synonyms) :
 self.word = input_word
 self.synonyms = input_synonyms
```

A Thesaurus is a list of Entry

```
e1 = Entry("dog", ["doggie", "puppy"])
e2 = Entry("cat", ["kitty"])
Thesaurus = [e1, e2]
```

A Corpus is a list of Documents, and each Document is a list of strings.

```
doc1 = ["this", "is", "a", "single”, “document"]
doc2 = ["this", "is", "another", "document"]
Corpus = [doc1, doc2]
```

I have tried to play around by storing the count in the "store" variable but it always return 0. I think something is either wrong because I do not capture the correct keyword, or I do not store "count" properly.

Here is my code :

```
def search(keyword) :
 all_words = [keyword]
 for entry in Thesaurus: 
   if entry.word == keyword:
     for word in entry.synonyms:
       all_words.append(word)
 store = []
 for search_word in all_words:
   count = 0
      for document in Corpus: 
     for word in document:
       if search_word == word:
         count = count + 1
   store.append([search_word, count])
 return store

input = "happy"
output = search(input)
print(output)
```

What I am getting at the moment is:

```
[['happy', 0]]
```

The expected result should something among those line:

```
[('happy', 16), ('glad', 2), ('pleased', 2), ('delighted', 2), ('joyous', 1)]
```

Comment: Can you pleas share the actual values of `Thesaurus` and `Corpus` that you're using? With the ones you gave in the question, `[['happy', 0]]` is exactly the expected result (none of the thesauruses include `happy`, nor do the sample documents). But it seems, based on the "expected result", that you were actually testing with some synonyms for `happy` and a text that included each of those words several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, however, I found some indentation issues and corrected them.

```
class Entry :
    def __init__(self, input_word, input_synonyms) :
        self.word = input_word
        self.synonyms = input_synonyms

e1 = Entry("dog", ["doggie", "puppy"])
e2 = Entry("cat", ["kitty"])
Thesaurus = [e1, e2]
doc1 = ["dog", "is", "a", "puppy", "and", "a", "puppy", "is", "doggie"]
doc2 = ["this", "is", "another", "document"]
Corpus = [doc1, doc2]

def search(keyword) :
    all_words = [keyword]
    for entry in Thesaurus:
        if entry.word == keyword:
            for word in entry.synonyms:
                all_words.append(word)
    store = []
    for search_word in all_words:
        count = 0
        for document in Corpus:
            for word in document:
                if search_word == word:
                    count = count + 1
        store.append([search_word, count])
    return store

inp = "dog"
output = search(inp)
print(output)
```

It returns the following:

```
[['dog', 1], ['doggie', 1], ['puppy', 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you,  my issue was that the order of my code!